# Remove file extension and keep parameters on nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I'm trying to make url on my server seo friendly.

Original: /face.php?name=hello-stackoverflow123

Desired: /face/hello-stackoverflow123

I made those little configs:

```
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @extensionless-php;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location @extensionless-php {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }
```

**Problem 1:** I can't find a config to keep the parameters it gives me always 404 (so I get 404 if I try face/hello-stackoverflow123

**Problem 2:** If I have a file faces.php it will open if I try/faces, but if I open faces.php it won't redirect to /faces

Comment: From the example URI `/face/hello-stackoverflow123` you provided, how could it be determined if this URI should be served as `/face/hello-stackoverflow.php` or as `/face.php?name=hello-stackoverflow123`? Your config will try only `/face/hello-stackoverflow.php`, that is the way it works. And of course it won't redirect you from `/faces.php` to `faces`, it isn't supposed to do so. The whole question sounds quite strange, like "I found something on Google and it doesn't work the way I want it to, why?"

Comment: If you want for some assistance, you should at least specify the request processing rules, for example, "for the request `/a/b/c` try `/a/b/c.php` first then `/a/b.php?arg=c` then `/a.php?arg1=b&arg2=c` then 404 error". Otherwise it is completely unclear what you are trying to achieve.